# URIError: malformed URI sequence with JQuery Ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to load a page with URL which contains some special character (ü) into the tab made from JQuery. But I get this error:

```
URIError: malformed URI sequence
```

Do you guys have any idea about this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURIComponent(url`) to urlencode the special characters properly.

Comment: Thanks Uku Loskit, I found another solution, I used normal character for tab's name and update it after tabs create.
Before I put some think like this <li>tüb</li> and create tabs.

Comment: great to hear that you managed to solve it, you can post it as an answer to your own question and accept it